# Can not use Vodafone Connect Pen K3806-z (12.04)

Tags: usb

I have a Vodafone Connect Pen K3806-z and I'm trying to use with Ubuntu 12.04.
I already Google about this and try many solution but without success.

When I connect the USB Pen, the device is recognize:

```
usb-devices
-----------
...
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=19d2 ProdID=1013 Rev=00.01
S:  Manufacturer=Vodafone (ZTE)
S:  Product=K3806-Z
S:  SerialNumber=ACC81D40E48EA6EA72D3C0E77795A0E18981CE10
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
...
```

But no USB drive is mounted.
When I look into `dmesg`, I get this:

```
[ 2707.722378] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 2716.870415] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2716.887337] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=1013
[ 2716.887344] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[ 2716.887348] usb 3-2: Product: K3806-Z
[ 2716.887351] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Vodafone (ZTE)
[ 2716.887354] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: ACC81D40E48EA6EA72D3C0E77795A0E18981CE10
[ 2716.888078] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 2717.885505] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Vodafone USB SCSI CD-ROM  0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 2717.885884] scsi 8:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Vodafone Storage          0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 2717.887579] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[ 2717.887831] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 2717.888021] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[ 2717.888399] sd 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 2717.889194] sd 8:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 2717.949242] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 2717.949258] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 2717.949263] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 2718.026150] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 4 ep 2 with no TDs queued?
[ 2718.220919] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 2718.220936] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 2718.220941] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is your exact problem? The device shows up in `dmesg` it should be available in Network Manager you probably just need to run the mobile broadband wizard, like so: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330820/vodafone-mobile-broadband-for-ubunt/330849#330849

Comment: VodaFone don't support this Pen for Ubuntu only for Windows and Mac, so I don't have a wizard to follow. I allready try to configure a connection througth Ubuntu "Network Connections" but I can't find the connection to turn it on.

Comment: The APN settings you are using are probably incorrect. Unfortunately I don't know what the correct ones are, and sometimes the ones provided in the Mobile Broadband Provider Information package that Network Manager uses for its wizard, are incorrect. Be careful though, as using incorrect APN settings may allow you to connect, but may be on the wrong tariff to suit your contract or plan. Look at 'APN', 'username', 'password'  'PAP', 'CHAP' and ask your provider what they are meant to be or copy them from the windows wizard if you can use it on a windows machine

Comment: I can check APN setting on a windows machine. But after I configure a connection througth "Ubuntu Network Connections" the profile that I configure doesn't appear anyhwere. So, the questions is, How can I use that connection?

Comment: I see what you are saying now you may need to make a config file in /etc/usb_modeswitch.d try `cat /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/19d2:1013` to see if it first exists

Comment: The folder /etc/usb_modeswitch.d is empty

Comment: Can you go to your home folder right click on usb device and eject then see if it is recognised by network manager

Comment: I can't see any device mount, so I can't do what you ask me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actual support for that was added in [3.11](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/255728/). This means at least Ubuntu 13.10.